# List view inside a fragment not being populated from firebase but I can save data to may firebase DB

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a MainActivity.Java class that uses a view pager to render my fragments. One of the fragment is called DashBoardFrag, that is supposed to pick data from my firebase DB and populate it on an List view. Currently I can send data and save it to the firebas but I can't retrieve. Retrieval is supposed to happen when the DashBoardFrag is loaded or displayed to user.When I run my app, it doesn't crash but again nothing is being displayed. This is my `onCreateView method` inside `DashBoardFrag` fragment

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the fragment_dash_board for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dash_board, container, false);
    newsListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newslist_view);

    dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dbOperationsHelper = new DBOperationsHelper(dbref);

    /**
     * SET ADAPTER
     */

     //dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),dbOperationsHelper.retrieveNews());
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dbOperationsHelper.retrieveNews());

    //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "MUST NOT BE EMPTY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     newsListView.setAdapter(dbAdapter);


    return rootView;

}
```

This is my `DBOperationsHelper` class

```
public class DBOperationsHelper {
DatabaseReference dbref;
Boolean saved;
ArrayList<String> newsArraylist = new ArrayList<>();

public DBOperationsHelper(DatabaseReference db){
    this.dbref = db;
}

public Boolean save(DBModel news){
    if(news == null){
        saved = false;
    }else{
        try {
            dbref.child("DBModel").push().setValue(news);
            saved = true;
        } catch (DatabaseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            saved = false;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}

private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    newsArraylist.clear();
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        String news = ds.getValue(DBModel.class).getNewsHead();
        newsArraylist.add(news);
    }
}

/**
 * RETRIEVE NEWS
 */
public ArrayList<String> retrieveNews(){
   dbref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
         fetchData(dataSnapshot);
       }

       @Override
       public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           fetchData(dataSnapshot);
       }

       @Override
       public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
    return newsArraylist;
}
}
```

This is my `DBModel class`

```
public class DBModel {
boolean bool;
String name, email, username, pass, newsHead, newsBody;

public void setIsLogin(boolean bl){
    this.bool = bl;

}
public boolean getIsLogin(){
    return this.bool;
}

public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;

}
public String getEmail(){
    return this.email;
}

public void setUsername(String username){
    this.username = username;

}
public String getUsername(){
    return this.username;
}

public void setPass(String pass){
    this.pass = pass;

}
public String getPass(){
    return this.pass;
}

public void setNewsHead(String nws_name){
    this.newsHead = nws_name;

}

public String getNewsHead() {
    return newsHead;
}

public void setNewsBody(String newsBody) {
    this.newsBody = newsBody;
}

public String getNewsBody() {
    return newsBody;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have managed to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to populate my recycler(Changed from using a listview to recyclerview).

[image]

Here is what I did.

**1.Changed my `DBModel(NewsModel)` object class to have `getters` and `setters` for the details I want to display and retrieve as shown**

```
   public class NewsModel {
    String email, username, pass, newsHead, newsBody;


public NewsModel() {
}

public NewsModel(String newsHead, String newsBody) {
    this.newsHead = newsHead;
    this.newsBody = newsBody;

}

public String getNewsHead() {
    return newsHead;
}

public void setNewsHead(String nws_name){
    this.newsHead = nws_name;

}

public String getNewsBody() {
    return newsBody;
}

public void setNewsBody(String newsBody) {
    this.newsBody = newsBody;
}


}
```

**2.Edited my fragment by creating an inner static class that extended the `RecyclerViewHolder`, that I used to set the values of the textfields, as shown**

```
DatabaseReference dbref;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NewsModel,NewsModelVH> firebasenewsRecycleAdapter ;
RecyclerView newsrecyclerView;
LinearLayoutManager nwlinearLayoutManager;
ArrayList<NewsModel> newsArraylist = new ArrayList<>();



public static class NewsModelVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView newsHead, newsBody;

    public NewsModelVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.newsHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listview_item_title);
        this.newsBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listview_item_short_description);
       }
    }// End NewsModelVH class

public static final String NEWS= "NewsModel";
```

And edited my onCreateView method to use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` that uses the `DBModel class`  `DatabaseReference` and `RecyclcerViewHolder` as shown

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the fragment_dash_board for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_rv, container, false);
    newsrecyclerView =(RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_noticeboard);
    nwlinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    nwlinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    firebasenewsRecycleAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NewsModel, NewsModelVH>(
            NewsModel.class,
            R.layout.fragment_dashboard_imagetext,
            NewsModelVH.class,
            dbref.child(NEWS)) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(NewsModelVH viewHolder, NewsModel model, int position) {
            viewHolder.newsHead.setText(model.getNewsHead());
            viewHolder.newsBody.setText(model.getNewsBody());
        }
    };

    firebasenewsRecycleAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver(){
        @Override
         public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount){
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            int newsCount = firebasenewsRecycleAdapter.getItemCount();
            int lastVisiblePosition = nwlinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            if(lastVisiblePosition == -1 || (positionStart>= (newsCount -1) && lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart -1))){
                newsrecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
            }
        }
    });
    newsrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(nwlinearLayoutManager);
    newsrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebasenewsRecycleAdapter);

    /**
     * SET ADAPTER
     */

    ProgressBar newsprogressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    newsprogressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Log.v("RETRIEVE", " dbOperationsHelper.retrieveNews() NEWS=" + dbref);

    return rootView;

}
```

One thing that still eats my head though is why the data is being displayed and I have neither used `dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()` or `ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()`

Well, something tells me things might limit me in future to achieve some things...not sure of what yet but I will know when that time comes. But if there is someone who has an explanation to this can also share info.

Otherwise, hope this helps someone so that you don't get stuck for two days switching between adtapters(`ArrayAdapter`, `ArrayList`, `CustomeAdapter`, `FirebaseListAdapter` and finally `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`) to find a solution.

Comment: Actually FirebaseRecyclerAdapter is already have their listener on it, once it called the adapter will populate the data after firebasenewsRecycleAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<....>(..,..,..,..dbref.child(NEWS))

Answer (score 0):

After two days of trying, I managed to retrieve data on a list view, the only thing I changed is instead of using ArrayAdapters, I used my custom Adapter.
Inside `onCreateView method` 
I changed

`arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dbOperationsHelper.retrieveNews());`

to

`dbAdapter = newDBAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), dbOperationsHelper.retrieveNews());`

Inside `DBOperationsHelper` I changed the ArrayList to take DBModel object and not string object as shown

`ArrayList<String> newsArraylist = new ArrayList<>();`

to

`ArrayList<DBModel> newsArraylist = new ArrayList<>();`

Also changed `fetchData method` to look like this

```
    private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    newsArraylist.clear();
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        DBModel news = ds.getValue(DBModel.class);
        newsArraylist.add(news);
        Log.v("FIREBASE RETRIEVE", "index=" + ds.getValue(DBModel.class));
    }

}
```

but the problem now is, When the fragment is first started, It does not show anything, but when I add new record to the firebase database then do several refresh on the fragment, the data finally comes and is displayed in a weird manner as shown in the picture below. Anyone who has an idea of what is happening?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use firebase ui , add  compile '`com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.1`' in dependacy then follow this
https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/index.html

Comment: The reason why I didn't opt for ```firebase-ui``` is because I want my list view to have both image, title and short description. Will ```firebase-ui``` help me achieve that? Does it mean the reason as to why the data displayed in my listview as shown in the picture is because I'm not using ```firebase-ui``` ? Also why does the data display after several refreshments and not just the first time my fragment is displayed?

Comment: you can supply your own layout in firebase ui. also try using value event listener instead of child added listener.

Comment: I finally implemented the FirebaseListAdapter as per  this [link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) tutorial but now the problem is that only one cardview is being shown and no data is displayed on it. Unlike when I used my custom adapter all the cardviews depending on data that is on database were being dsiplayed. I decided to use Child added listener because my listview is not static, it needs to have data synchronised/in real time as it gets added to the database.

Comment: `firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<DBModel>(getActivity(), DBModel.class, R.layout.fragment_dashboard_imagetext, dbref) {
            DBModel dbModel = new DBModel();
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View view, DBModel news, int position) {
                ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview_item_title)).setText(dbModel.getNewsHead());
                ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview_item_short_description)).setText(dbModel.getNewsBody());

            }
        };
        newsListView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);`

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same problem but with reading the documentation solve them in my case use Firebase IU for the Recyclerview and to get the UID use position in the following code is an example of how I use it in my application.

In the recyclerview that uses the viewholder it contained a title, content and image.

```
public class NoticiaFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private Boolean bool;

private LinearLayoutManager mManager;

FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference databaseReference=database.getReference();

@Nullable
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View tab_noticia=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_noticias,container,false);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)tab_noticia.findViewById(R.id.recyclerNoticias);

    mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());



    mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mManager);


    if (recyclerView!=null){
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }



    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoticiaModel,NoticiaViewHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
            <NoticiaModel, NoticiaViewHolder>(
            NoticiaModel.class,R.layout.tab_noticias_card,NoticiaViewHolder.class,
           databaseReference.getRef()
                    .child("smiledu")
                    .child("avantgard")
                    .child("noticias")) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(NoticiaViewHolder viewHolder, NoticiaModel model, int position) {
            viewHolder.textView.setText(model.getNombre_noticia());

            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(model.getFoto_noticia())
                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
            DatabaseReference databaseReference=getRef(position);
            databaseReference.keepSynced(true);
            final String UID=databaseReference.getKey();

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),NoticiaDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("uid",UID);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return tab_noticia;
}
public static class  NoticiaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    public NoticiaViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.noticia_card_image);
        textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.noticia_card_titulo);
        mView=itemView;
    }
 }
}
```